# I apparently created a wiki excerpt in 2016 before creating my account in 2017

Tags: bug, tag-wikis, profile-page

My [activity timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/471884/thesimplifire?tab=activity&sort=all&page=314) says I created a wiki excerpt for [geometric-programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-programming) in 2016 (I did [in 2019](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2040839/revisions)). I registered on SE in 2017.

How did SE manage to read 9 upside down?

Comment: Wait, you still believe time is linear???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following old bug report on Meta SE seems to be identical to what you observed: [Activity log entry before registration date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110741).

Though that report is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), it seems that there is a regression of this bug on at least two other SE sites:

- Anime & Manga SE: [According to the activity tab of my profile, I performed some actions on a site before joining](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246351)
- Science Fiction & Fantasy SE: [How could I create a tag wiki three years before I joined the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294920)

Looks like we can now add Mathematics SE to this list as well.